Why is HTTP live streaming not working using VLC?
I'm trying to set up HTTP live streaming (HLS) with a webcam, just over the local network, using VLC. I've successfully been able to do other types of streaming (e.g. http) with the same webcam, but I'd like to get HLS working (the livehttp module) because of it's extra features.
The camera I'm using is a USB Logitech webcam and shows as HD Pro Webcam C920.
Here is my command. I've tried to change around the settings, but no matter what I do the video doesn't show up (in the browser). It seems to load the page and it says "Live Broadcast" but no video. See screenshot at the bottom of the question.
cvlc -v v4l2://"$cam" --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,fps=20,vb=512,scale=1,acodec=none,venc=x264{aud,profile=high,level=60,keyint=15,bframes=0,ref=1,nocabac}}:std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=true,numsegs=5,index=/var/www/html/streaming/mystream.m3u8,index-url=10.0.0.19/streaming/stream-###.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/var/www/html/streaming/stream-###.ts}}"

($cam is the path to the camera. In my case it is /dev/video0. I didn't write it here, since it changes depending on the cameras connected.)

Edit (Dec 13, 2024): I'd still like to get this working. If there is anyone who has successfully streamed with HLS on VLC, please comment. Thanks.


Does the camera support this? If you use a program like Wireshark what data is traveling between the camera and VLC?

Yes, of course it does. The other commands for streaming work fine. It's a USB webcam by the way.

If it helps, it is a Logitech webcam and shows as "HD Pro Webcam C920."

Please put that information in the main question body, so it will be helpful to those reading the question.

Where is $cam defined, what does it contain?

@tink It is the path to the camera. In my case it is /dev/video0. I didn't write it here, since it changes depending on the cameras connected.

@tink, I don't know if you saw my reply, since the comment is hidden. I also added it to the post.
